# "Утолить желание" українською

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як перекласти з російської вислів "утолить желание"?

В мережі знайшла кілька варіантів: вгамувати бажання, втамувати бажання, приборкати бажання. Який з них правильний?

Comment: Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання про переклад містило: (1) пояснення **своїми словами** іншомовного слова; (2) **контекст**, в якому автор збирається використовувати перекладене слово; (3) продемонструвати власну спробу знайти відповідь і (4) пояснити, чим са́ме знайдені варіанти не підходять. Запитання, які не відповідають цим умовам, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Answer (score 2):

Слід сказати, що (рос.) «утолить» бажання можна двома кардинально різними, чи навіть протилежними, способами:

1. Піддатись йому і (можливо, виконавши якісь дії для цього) **отримати те, чого бажаєш** (випити води, поїсти їжі, зустрітися з коханою людиною).
2. Силою волі, переключенням уваги чи якимись іншими засобами примусити себе (тимчасово чи остаточно) **перестати бажати** (чи зменшити силу потягу), **не отримуючи бажаного** (а навпаки — фактично відмовившись від нього).

Відповідно, українські відповідники російського «утолить» можуть попадати в одну з нижченаведених категорій.

#### Універсальні слова, що можуть використовуватися в обох значеннях

- **вгамувати**,
- **втамувати**.

Мені здається, це слідує прямо з визначень цих слів у «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах:

> [УГАМО́ВУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ughamovuvaty) (ВГАМО́ВУВАТИ), ую, уєш, недок., УГАМУВА́ТИ (ВГАМУВА́ТИ), ую, уєш, док., перех. <…> 4. Зменшувати, задовольняти (голод, спрагу і т. ін.). До голоду долучилася спрага. Володя знайшов соковите листя. Воно нагадувало на смак капусту.. Юнак жував його, листя хрумтіло на зубах, сік сповнював рот. Але це мало вгамовувало спрагу (Олесь Донченко, III, 1956, 236); Я переліз через паркан, помацки нарвав слив, щоб угамувати голод, і ліг в садку на лаві (Петро Панч, На калиновім мості, 1965, 43); Вона з небувалою насолодою спочатку угамувала спрагу, а тоді занурила обличчя з запаленими повіками в свіжу й холодну вологу (Зінаїда Тулуб, В степу.., 1964, 94). <…>
>
> ---
>
> [УТАМО́ВУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/utamovuvaty) (ВТАМО́ВУВАТИ), ую, уєш, недок., УТАМУВА́ТИ (ВТАМУВА́ТИ), ую, уєш, док., перех.
>
> 1. Переборювати, стримувати, припиняти вияв якого-небудь почуття або відчуття. Сліз не можу втамувати, щасливих, гордих сліз... Все гладжу плечі [сина] (Володимир Сосюра, II, 1958, 471); Він ніяк не міг втамувати тремтіння (Олександр Бойченко, Молодість, 1949, 35); Втамовуючи страх, Василько ішов між ними [жандармами] вперед (Агата Турчинська, Зорі.., 1950, 78);
>   //  Ослабляти, заглушати. Йшла [Надія], спотикаючись, мало не бігла. І хотілося йти ще швидше, немов це могло хоч трохи утамувати той біль (Яків Баш, Надія, 1960, 88).
>
> 2. Задовольняти голод, спрагу і т. ін. Утамувала левиця жагу, із джерела напившись (Микола Зеров, Вибр., 1966, 323).

Євгенія Час у посібнику «Чи правильно ми говоримо» [намагається ретельніше дослідити ці слова](http://chak-chy-pravylno-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/t#tamuvaty-gamuvaty) — але суттєвої різниці між ними я поки що не побачив.

#### «Утолить» у значенні «отримати те, чого бажаєш»

- **[виконати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9146&page=322)**,
- **[втілити](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=16716&page=558)**,
- **[задовольнити](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=29071&page=962)**,
- **[здійснити](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35722&page=1130)**,
- **[реалізувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/realizuvaty)**.

#### «Утолить» у значенні «перестати бажати, не отримуючи бажаного»

- **[перебороти](http://sum.in.ua/s/pereborjuvaty)**,
- **[приспати](http://sum.in.ua/s/prysypljaty)**.

#### Некатегоризоване

В мене особисто слово **приборкати** асоціюється з другим значенням — «„утолить“ у значенні „перестати бажати, не отримуючи бажаного“». Але оскільки я непевен у цьому, то поки що залишу це слово окремо. В будь-якому разі, це слово можна теж застосовувати до бажань, про це свідчить означення у СУМ-11:

> [ПРИБО́РКУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryborkuvaty), ую, уєш, недок., ПРИБО́РКАТИ, аю, аєш, док., перех. <…> 2. <…> // Стримувати прояв, зменшувати силу, швидкість і т. ін. чого-небудь. Розпалити уяву людей неважко, та як її потім приборкувати?.. (Микола Руденко, Остання шабля, 1959, 286); <…> Тяжке сирітство з самого малку, гірка неволя у чужій роботі приборкали її шибку думку (Панас Мирний, II, 1954, 256); Це було більше, ніж бажання. Бажання можна приспати, приборкати, вбити, зрештою (Юрій Мушкетик, День.., 1967, 3); <…>